# Is it possible to only link a project without compiling when using visual studio 2019?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, msbuild

In my project, there is a common header file shared by many source files. Usually, a modification of the header only affects several source files. I want to recompile those files manually and then let vs to link the project.

Comment: I guess you mean the header is included into other translation units, but you don't want to re-compile them. as the change you made does not affect them? Unfortunately, I don't think there's an easy way to do it.

Comment: @Alex Guteniev Yes.

Comment: You can manually run `cl /c` and `link` without the help of IDE, but I don't think this is an acceptable solution

Comment: I recommend breaking up this header file so the build system can do it's job for you.

Comment: What is the problem here? If you compile a source file from the IDE (right click on the file and Compile), VS knows about it and on next build it will not be compiled again. What are you trying to achieve that the IDE cannot do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, compile your C++ files only (ctrl-F7). Then link the project (right click project, then "Project only" -> Link), then run. In Options => Build And Run, make sure you specify "Prompt to build" when projects are out of date, and then choose to run instead of build. Good luck!